# RTSP Url of video not working in VideoView

Tags: android, video, streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I am creating video playing app from Youtube. I have extracted Video Data using gdata API and got 3gp url for format 1,6. This i got extracted from Media:Group --> Media:content element.
My Device Info Android 4.0.3 and Model Micromax P350.

These video is working in VLC Player but not in `VideoView` enter code here in my app. Here is my code:

```
 <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
       android:paddingLeft="2px"
       android:paddingRight="2px"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:paddi`enter code here`ngTop="2px"
       android:paddingBottom="2px"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

          <VideoView 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/VideoView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            //MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            // mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            //videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

            videoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://v1.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQneb1Sj_PGnoRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp");


            videoView.start();  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be your video is not in one of the supported formats:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Hi, This video Url is from Youtube and is playing fine in VLC. but not in my application. And this happening in same device.

Comment: It can happen in the same device, YouTube doesn't have to use VideoView same as your app does.

Comment: Like streaming from same url is working in VLC than it should have worked in VideoView or some like control in android. Can You point me toward right way for steaming in android app? thanks

Comment: Live streaming in android controls is very limited. Often one has to resort to writing decoding in the native code. I don't know about YouTube app but there are open source videoplayers for android such as https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/ you can have an idea from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
//play rtsp stream  
private void PlayRtspStream(String rtspUrl){  
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(rtspUrl));  
    videoView.requestFocus();  
    videoView.start();
}
```